# What happened to Marshall and Lily's trip to Rome?

Tags: how-i-met-your-mother

In *How I Met Your Mother* they made a big deal of Marshall and Lily's trip to Rome but then we only see a very short scene of them in Italy. I would have expected at least a couple of episodes. So what happened to it?

Comment: Its seems they didn't spent much time there. And HIMYM normally works with all the characters at one place.

Answer (score 3):

*How I Met Your Mother* is told from Ted's point of view. He didn't make the trip to Rome, so he wouldn't have a lot of details about the trip to tell to his children years later.

Answer (score 1):

In HIMYM most episodes have all the characters at one place. Keeping Lilly and Marshal away from the rest of the characters would not be that much fun I guess

Comment: There are several episodes where the group is split: when Lily runs away to San Francisco, when Marshall Travels alone to Barney and Robin's wedding, Robin goes to work in Japan...

Comment: @algiogia If I remember correctly, those story lines where the group wasn't all together were mostly due to outside forces, such as pregnancies or actors working on other projects.